# Check for specific enum values in RequestParam Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, enums, parameters, controller

I have a Spring Boot API with some controllers that use an enum as a RequestParam. This all works fine. If I use a value that is not in the enum, I will get an error. However, I can't seem to find anywhere if it is possible to validate if the requestParam is part of a subset of the enum.

The enum looks something like this:

```
public enum Type {
    @JsonProperty("een")
    ONE("een"),

    @JsonProperty("twee")
    TWO("twee"),

    @JsonProperty("drie")
    THREE("drie");

    private final String value;

    private static final Map<String, Type> lookup = new HashMap<String, Type>();

    static {
        for (Type type : Type.values()) {
            lookup.put(type.value, type);
        }
    }

    private Type(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static Type get(String value) {
        return lookup.get(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

I have created a org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter in order to use the enum like this (value with different enum name).

The endpoints look something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/my-endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Item>> getItems(
        @RequestParam Type type
    ) {
        <... etc>
    return new ResponseEntity<Set<Item>>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So for example I would like to validate for one of my endpoints if the RequestParam has value "een" or "twee" and should return a bad request if it has value "drie". And for another endpoint I would like to validate if the RequestParam has value "twee" or "drie". This is a simplified example, in reality I have a lot more options in the enum and a lot mare endpoints that use all or a subset of the enum.
I know I could create different enums with the subsets, but because the they are used often in different subsets each time, this is not really an option.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this through this article: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums.

Basically, I created a annotation specific for my enum (I'm not sure if this can be made more generic).

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = TypeSubsetValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface TypeSubset {
    Type[] anyOf();

    String message() default "error.wrongType";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And created the accompanying validator:

```
 public class TypeSubsetValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TypeSubset, Type> {
    private Type[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(TypeSubset annotation) {
        this.subset = annotation.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Type value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

Than the validation can be used like this:

```
@GetMapping("/my-endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Item>> getItems(
        @TypeSubset(anyOf = { Type.ONE, Type.TWO}) @RequestParam  Type type
    ) {
        <... etc>
    return new ResponseEntity<Set<Item>>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now only Type.ONE en Type.TWO can be used as RequestParam, other values will return a bad request.